# What is the type of the underlying stream of a boost::iostreams::filtering_stream?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-iostreams

I have this stream that performs decompression using Boost.Iostreams:

```
struct istream_zlib
  : public boost::iostreams::filtering_stream<boost::iostreams::input, char>
{
  istream_zlib(std::istream& in)
  {
    push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());
    push(in);
  }
};
```

Now, I would like to access the underlying stream (`std::istream& in`) later on. Naively, I thought that requesting a `std::istream` through `component()` would do it, but the pointer I get back is `null`:

```
auto ptr = component<std::istream>(1); // ptr is null!
```

What type should I provide to `component()` for doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not real, since not `istream` will be pushed into `filtering_stream` (for my boost 1.48 it will be `boost::iostreams::detail::mode_adapter<boost::iostreams::input, std::istream>` for example), you can check it type by `component_type` function. However, I have no ideas, why you need to get `stream` from `filtering_stream`, since you send reference - you should have this object in places, where you use this `filtering_stream`.

Also, you can use `reference_wrapper` for this case (i.e `push(boost::ref(in));`) and then get it by component using

```
auto ptr = component<boost::reference_wrapper<std::istream>>(1);
```

Comment: I want to access where the cursor is located through `tellg()` to compute the progress of the decompression... I will store the reference to the `std::istream` but that was to avoid having another member if it is already stored somewhere else, if possible. Thanks,

Comment: While using `tellg()` on the stream does not report an updated cursor position (too bad), your solution does allow to access the underlying stream! Thanks.